# Loading initial data of webpage with ajax in masonry layout

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, masonry

this is the ajax which i am using to get data from a php file

```
$.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "content.php",
      data: somevariable,
      dataType: "text",                  
      success: function(response) {
        $(this).parent().find(".loadingdataimage").hide();
        $content.html(response);
      }.bind(this)
  });
```

Now how can i make this code to get initial data of the page from content.php file whenever page loads

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question properly, but I would assume you just want to call this code in the "document ready" handler.

Comment: yes when page loads so that i can get data from mysql database using ajax call

Comment: will that help if i directly use document ready?? @octopoid

Comment: Yeah, if you want to pull the contents of that page over into a variable as soon as the page loads, call the above code when the document is ready. If you put it into a function you can call it when the pages loads and also whenever else you need.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370) can help a lot to avoid the close of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Octopoid is on to the right solution, here is an example on how to do it using JQuery:

```
$.ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "content.php",
    data: somevariable,
    dataType: "text",                  
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).parent().find(".loadingdataimage").hide();
      $content.html(response);
    }.bind(this)
  });
});
```

If you want to separate the logic into a function, that you can call again, you could achieve it like this:

```
var refresh = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "content.php",
    data: somevariable,
    dataType: "text",                  
    success: function(response) {
      $(this).parent().find(".loadingdataimage").hide();
      $content.html(response);
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
$.ready(refresh);
```